# PHP regex - replace text between multiple tags with link

Tags: php, regex

I have string who look like this

```
A <<double>> <<tripod>> (for holding a <<plate>>, etc.) with six feet, of which three rest on the ground, in whatever position it is placed.
```

How can I replace it in format that everything between << >> become a link.

Result should look like this:

```
A <a href="search/double">double</a> <a href="search/tripod">tripod</a> (for holding a <a href="search/plate">plate</a>, etc.) with six feet, of which three rest on the ground, in whatever position it is placed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$str = "A <<double>> <<tripod>> (for holding a <<plate>>, etc.) with six feet, of which three rest on the ground, in whatever position it is placed.";

    preg_match_all("|<<(.*)>>|U", $str, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    for($i=0; $i < count($out[0]); $i++) {
        $str = str_replace($out[0][$i], '<a href="search/'. $out[1][$i] .'">'. $out[1][$i] .'</a>', $str);
    }

echo $str;
```

Another alternative is to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and create a recursive function:

```
function parseTags($input) {
    $regex = "|<<(.*)>>|U";

    if (is_array($input)) {
        $input = '<a href="search/'.$input[1].'">'.$input[1].'</a>';
    }

return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'parseTags', $input);
}

$str = "A <<double>> <<tripod>> (for holding a <<plate>>, etc.) with six feet, of which three rest on the ground, in whatever position it is placed.";

echo parseTags($str);
```